# CentOS 7 and X11R6 Installation

Tags: centos, fonts

OK so I know just enough about Linux to make me dangerous. As exemplified here:

I need CentOS 7 for some newer tools I use, but I also require the use of some older tools. These older tools need X11R6 to function properly. While I know it is not advised to install it, I've done so before (on Linux Mint) and it caused no problems. So I went ahead and installed X11R6 on Centos 7. Everything seemed to work just fine afterward, until I launched one of my newer tools (that does not require X11R6) and it displayed all characters as rectangular boxes, which obviously indicates a font problem. This same program worked just fine before I installed X11R6.

While I realize installation of X11R6 is not recommended, I do need X11R6, so can anyone suggest anything I can try to get this font problem fixed without uninstalling X11R6?

Comment: Would running these in a VM be an option?

Comment: I am running CentOS 7 in a VM. You mean run a separate VM with an older OS that uses X11R6?

Comment: Pretty much. That would simplify things hugely. Then you can possibly use x forwarding with the older tools, I suppose